# Why do people grunt while playing tennis?

Tags: tennis

A lot of tennis players, from professional to recreational, grunt when they hit the ball while playing tennis. Is there a reason for this?

**related:**

http://regressing.deadspin.com/why-do-tennis-players-grunt-because-it-works-1597557402

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunting_in_tennis

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning it was probably a reaction generated by the effort to hit the ball. It is a natural reaction under stress in phase of respiration.

Now is almost becoming a "trademark " made ​​in a more emphasize, maybe also to distract the opponent

Comment: I had down-voted this question so as to not mislead future readers, but I removed it since the first two sentences are spot-on. Indeed, imagine one were to lift something really heavy, maybe unsuccessfully: a grunt would be very likely. The final sentence, however, is almost complete nonsense =P -- yes, there is the *occasional* person who does this, but the overwhelming majority of the time it's that people are working hard and exerting considerable physical effort. [continued...]

Comment: One thing overlooked in tennis is how much effort goes into *hitting* the ball. People often talk about the distance run, but actually hitting the ball is serious effort, for both the legs and the arms/upper body. One has to compress down, then really explode up with the legs. Unless it's a very running-based match, this is the most tiring bit, not the running side-to-side/up-and-down. [Ok, apparently I can't change my vote unless the answer is edited. I think a down-vote is fair by itself, but not necessary given the above comments...]